# image_picker flutter - ios simulator does not display image when image picking from gallery

Tags: ios, flutter

I use image_picker 0.8.5 package in flutter app for image uploading.
Below code is working well in android emulator, but ios simulator does not display image.

```
  List images = [[]];
  final _picker = ImagePicker();
  Future<void> _openImagePicker() async {
    final XFile? pickedImage =
        await _picker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    if (pickedImage != null) {
      setState(() {
        images[index].add(pickedImage);
      });
    }
  }
```

.......

```
Expanded(
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                child: Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    PhotoCarouselWidget(
                      ImageList: images[subindex],
                      onRemove: (int) {
                        setState(() {
                          images[subindex].removeAt(int);
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

In ios simulator console, I can get following error when I click image picker button.

```
VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(multiple_request, Cancelled by a second request, null, null)
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:177:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelImagePicker.getImage (package:image_picker_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_image_picker.dart:190:26)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _AddCounselStep1PageState._openImagePicker (package:laxia/views/pages/main/contribution/counsel_add_step1.dart:37:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
```

ios simulator is iPhone13(iOS15.4).
Please help me fix this error, display image in ios simulator.

Answer (score 0):

Image Picker doesn't show images picked from iOS Simulator. it is mentioned in the official docs of the image_picker page.
Have a read: https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker#installation

Starting with version 0.8.1 the iOS implementation uses PHPicker to pick (multiple) images on iOS 14 or higher. As a result of implementing PHPicker it becomes impossible to pick HEIC images on the iOS simulator in iOS 14+. This is a known issue. Please test this on a real device, or test with non-HEIC images until Apple solves this issue. 63426347 - Apple known issue

Comment: Yash Bhansali, I used jpeg image on simulator.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following key to info.plist and it worked fine for me

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>We need access to your photo library to pick an image for your profile.</string>
```